# Why I am getting these error during fetch api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api, setstate

I was trying to fetch the news API but I keep on getting this error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` is there any syntax or do I need to add something?
Please help me with this.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import NewsItem from './NewsItem'
   export default class News extends Component {
   constructor(){
   super();
   this.state={
       article : this.article
       }
   }
   
       async componentDidMount(){
       let urll = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines? 
        country=in&apiKey=6aeca0faebbd45c1a1ec3c463f703ebb";
       let data = await fetch(urll); 
       console.log(data)
       let parseData = await data.json() ; 
       console.log(parseData);
       this.setState({article : parseData.articles});
      }
   
        render() {
        return (
         <div className='newcontainer my-5'>
         <h1 className='mainheading' >PAHADI PRESS BREAKING NEWS</h1>
         {this.state.article.map((e)=>{
          return <div key={e.url} >
           <NewsItem  title={e.title} decription={e.description} imageUrl={e.urlToImage} 
           newsUrl={e.url}
           newsauthor={e.author}/>
         </div>
       })
     }
     </div>
     )
     }
     }
```

You can see in this image of the console what error I am getting->>
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOWkx.png

Comment: The error is indicating that whatever you're calling `map()` on is `undefined`. So it looks like the `this.state.article` property is `undefined` by the time it is rendered. Make sure that you're initializing it as an array as expected every  where you change your state.

Comment: Yes you are right when I am adding the api data manually in the file then everything seems fine, can you tell me how to make sure that it remains an arrray, or what I need to change in the code?

Comment: @Ankit Can you show in the post what shows your `console.log()` ?

Comment: David though the problem is solved but I will still show you the console if you are interested, moreover the console.log() didnt show anything after some time initiallt it was showing the arry. I have added the image in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in Tarek's answer, the `article` state is not initialized. The problem arises from the constructor, where you assign `{article: this.article}` to the state.

In the constructor, the instance is not yet accessible, it is indeed being constructed, which means that `this.article` does not exist yet, thus assigning `undefined` to the state.

You can instead assign it a default value, like an empty array: `this.state = {article: []}`. This should fix your problem.

`componentDidMount` is called after `render`, but you populate the state in `componentDidMount` and try to access it in `render`. `this.state.article` will thus always be `undefined` for a short period of time, causing the error you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much the problem is gone and thank you for this information.

Answer (score 0):

Your `article` state is not initialized. Make sure that you do that before the component renders.

Instead, you can use the optional chaining `?.` operator when calling the `map` method to not cause an error if `this.state.article` is nullish (`null` or `undefined`).
Example: `this.state.article?.map(...)`

Comment: I did this "  this.state?.article.map(...) " but the error is still there, how really I have to initilize the article. I want to make sure that it works everytime and I dont need to check if that is array or not

Comment: Sorry, it is `this.state.article?.map(...)`. I have updated my answer, check it again.

Comment: Put `?.` before calling the `map` method since `article` is `undefined` at component mount.

Comment: Using `?.` operator in this case will just return `undefined` instead of causing an error for calling a method on an `undefined` value.

Comment: Thank You I have initilized the article and the problem is gone.